# create and use android drawable reference in your android theme

Tags: android, android-xml, xml-drawable

I am having problem creating drawable reference in my styles
my styles.xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="myDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/lightColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/lightColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/lightColorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">@dimen/titleSize</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="msgreceivedbg">@drawable/mrrd</item>
</style>
<style name="myLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/darkColorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">@dimen/titleSize</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="msgreceivedbg">@drawable/mrrl</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and my attrs.xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="msgreceivedbg" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

when I try to use this attribute in my layout file, I got the following error

```
--------- beginning of crash
07-13 08:48:08.893 9913-9913/com.messaging.chatify E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.messaging.chatify, PID: 9913
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at com.messaging.chatify.Adapters.MessagesAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MessagesAdapter.java:125)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:726)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
    07-13 08:48:08.894 9913-9913/com.messaging.chatify E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040112 a=-1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:925)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4202)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:710)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:704)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:700)
        ... 66 more
```

I am using a recycler view for into which I inflate the view which uses a textView with the following line

```
android:background="?attr/msgreceivedbg"
```

the drawable mrrd and mrrl has just the color difference from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/darkColorPrimary" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

both the drawables just differs in the android:color property...

I am testing it on android 7.1.1 genymotion custom phone

the layout file is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_message_body6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="?attr/msgreceivedbg"
    android:maxWidth="240dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="hello, hello!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_message_time6"
    android:text="11:40"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:background="?attr/msgreceivedbg"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/text_message_body6"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/text_message_body6"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Can you post your layout xml file please?

Comment: I've update the post with layout file

Comment: Can you please explain, what are your trying to achieve here? Are you trying to have two different background style for your textviews in recyclerview?

Comment: Yes you can say that, I am just trying to change background of the textView when the theme is changed....

Comment: Post your code where you set your recyclerview adapter please

Comment: that is what I do that

RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reyclerview_message_list);

messagesAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mSource.getFriendsMessages(friend, messageCount));

recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MessagesDecorators(5));

recyclerView.setAdapter(messagesAdapter);

recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messagesAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);

Comment: Please see the answer, you have to set layout manager for your recycler view

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Based on the comments, here is the updated answer.

In your manifest xml file, you must use the same theme that you used for recycler view (unless you explicitly set your theme for the recycler view)

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```js
 <activity   android:theme="@style/myDark" 
            android:name=".YOUR_ACTIVITY />
```

**YOUR_ACTIVITY** is the activity where the recycler view is implemented.

If you are using a different theme for the activity you must explicitly set the theme in your recycler view as follows,

```java
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:theme="@style/myDark"
        android:id="@+id/rv1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: I just want to use xml drawable that will update the background color when theme is changed... your answers does not seems to be correct ...

Comment: your error is from not setting the recycler view properly, you have to set a layout manager for your recycler view, and also this will take effect only when you change the theme for your activity to one of your themes

Comment: this is my recycler view...…..                          <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reyclerview_message_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="418dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

Comment: I tested with your files and creating my own recycler view, and if you still face the problem, can you post the layout where you set the RecyclerView ?